# Zend Framework and clients User Agent

Tags: zend-framework, user-agent

I've created an application with the Zend Framework. Now I was asked to make an iphone webapp for it.

So my solution is to get the useragent and render a different view for it.

My searches on google lead to Zend_UserAgent but my library says it doesn't contain it. ;)
Is there any Zend way to find the useragent to render a different view or should I do it another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Zend_UserAgent was a proposal but Zend_Browser is chosen in favor of it. This will be included in future releases of ZF http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Browser+-+Interakting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** to determine which view to show. Here's a [list](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) of all available user agents.